# Application Variables in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

How would I go about setting and accessing application-wide variables in ASP.NET Core 2.0?

**Details:**
I have a variable, let's call it CompanyName, which resides in the database and is used on literally every page.  I don't want to hit the database every time I need to display the CompanyName. 100 years ago, I would have set `Application["CompanyName']=CompanyName` but I understand that this is not the way to do things in .NET Core. What would be the alternative?

Comment: Do you have other session context within your application for instance User / Tenant / Authorisation Claims or other Profile info that this variable belongs to or might be retrieved at the same time. In this case you could call on that. Or use some kind of data call/retrieval with caching?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A lot has progressed in the last 100 years. Some time ago, I believe in ASP.NET 1.0, the Application object in ASP classic was superseded with *caching* (although the Application object was left in for backward compatibility with ASP classic).

AspNetCore has [replaced the caching mechanism of ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory) and made it DI-friendly, but it is still very similar to how the state of things was in ASP.NET. The main difference is that you now need to inject it instead of using the static `HttpContext.Current.Cache` property.

Register the cache at startup...

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
}
```

And you can inject it like...

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IMemoryCache _cache;

    public HomeController(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _cache = memoryCache;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        string companyName = _cache[CacheKeys.CompanyName] as string;

        return View();
    }
```

Then to make it work application wide, you can use a [*filter*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters) or [*middleware*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?tabs=aspnetcore2x) combined with some sort of cache refresh pattern:

1. Attempt to get the value from the cache
2. If the attempt fails

   - Lookup the data from the database
   - Repopulate the cache
3. Return the value

---

```
public string GetCompanyName()
{
    string result;

    // Look for cache key.
    if (!_cache.TryGetValue(CacheKeys.CompanyName, out result))
    {
        // Key not in cache, so get data.
        result = // Lookup data from db

        // Set cache options.
        var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
            // Keep in cache for this time, reset time if accessed.
            .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60));

        // Save data in cache.
        _cache.Set(CacheKeys.CompanyName, result, cacheEntryOptions);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Of course, you could clean that up and make a service with strongly typed properties as a wrapper around your cache that is injected into controllers, but that is the general idea.

Note also there is a [*distributed cache*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed) in case you want to share data between web servers.

> You could alternatively use a static method or a statically registered class instance, but do note if hosting on IIS that the static will **go out of scope every time the application pool recycles**. So, to make that work, you would need to ensure your data is re-populated using a similar refresh pattern.
>
> The primary difference is that with caching there are timeout settings which can be used to optimize how long the data should be stored in the cache (either a hard time limit or a sliding expiration).

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to inject it into each controller. Perhaps inject it into a View Component instead?

Comment: That would work, too. Controllers are the most common place where dependencies are injected (which is why I chose that example), but it is not the only place where they can be. As I mentioned in my answer, *do* improve this solution  - creating your own wrapper around the cache that is injected everywhere and exposes the cache elements as strongly typed properties is perfectly fine.

Comment: I have it working in a View Component, plus I remove the item from cache when the Organization info is edited. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I like this solution and want to use it.  The difference in my situation is that I want to cache a list of items at the application level and I want to be able to prepend or append to the list from any user session and have that new information available to all users with their next request.  Should I get/set the entire list each time?  Should I lock the list before appending/prepending?

Answer (score 10):

You could create a Singleton-class called ApplicationWideSettings. Give that class public Properties. Initialize all the values you need one time and then use them by accesing the only instance of your class via:

```
ApplicationWideSettings.Instance.PropertyName;
```

Just make sure the namespace of the ApplicationWideSettings-class is referenced when you want to access it.

I prefer this over global/static settings because you have one class to save all your globally available data.

If you are unsure what a Singleton is I can just suggest you look into this article from Jon Skeet:

[C# In Depth: Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx)